# Aliasing the source table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

Is there a way to alias the source table in the context of a single scope ?

I tried this :

```rb
scope = User.all
scope.arel.source.left.table_alias = "toto"
scope.where(firstname: nil) => "SELECT `toto`.* FROM `users` `toto` WHERE `toto`.`firstname` IS NULL"
```

The problem is that the model class keeps the alias for all subsequent queries :

```rb
User.all => "SELECT `toto`.* FROM `users` `toto`"
```

**Edit**

I added this method to `ApplicationRecord`

```rb
def self.alias_source(table_alias)
  klass = Class.new(self)
  klass.all.source.left.table_alias = table_alias
  klass
end
```

Now, I can do :

```rb
User.alias_source(:toto).where(firstname: nil) => "SELECT `toto`.* FROM `users` `toto` WHERE `toto`.`firstname` IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since creating Anonymous Classes that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` will cause memory bloat, I am not sure I would recommend it (See Here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31395).

Maybe a better implementation would be to execute in a block form instead e.g. yield the aliased table to the block then set it back afterwards?

e.g.

```
def self.with_table_alias(table_alias, &block)
  begin 
    self.all.source.left.table_alias = table_alias
    block.call(self)
  ensure 
    self.all.source.left.table_alias = nil 
  end
end
```

Usage

```
User.with_table_alias(:toto) do |scope| 
  puts scope.joins(:posts).where(firstname: "Ruur").to_sql
end 
# "SELECT `toto`.* 
#  FROM 
#    `users` `toto` 
#    INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `toto`.`id` 
#  WHERE 
#    `toto`.`firstname` = 'Ruur'" 

puts User.all.to_sql
# "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
```

**WARNING: THIS HAS NOT BE TESTED BEYOND WHAT IS SHOWN HERE AND I WOULD NOT RECOMMEND THIS IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT WITHOUT EXTENSIVE TESTING FOR EDGE CASES AND OTHER GOTCHAS**

**Update** To address desired implementation

```
module ARTableAlias

  def alias_table_name=(val) 
    @alias_table_name = val 
  end 

  def alias_table_name 
    @alias_table_name ||= "#{self.table_name}_alias" 
  end   

  def alias_source
    @alias_klass ||= Class.new(self).tap do |k|
      k.all.source.left.table_alias = alias_table_name
    end  
  end 
end
```

Then usage as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  extend ARTableAlias 

  alias_table_name = :toto
end 

User.alias_source.where(first_name = 'Ruur') 
#=> SELECT `toto`.* FROM `users` `toto` WHERE `toto`.`first_name` = 'Ruur'
User.where(first_name = 'Ruur') 
#=> SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`first_name` = 'Ruur'
User.alias_source === User.alias_source
#=> true
```

Comment: That this means that anonymous classes are never garbage collected ? The memory keeps going up as you create them ? Or are we talking about extensively creating anonymous classes (creating thousands of them in test suits for example)

Comment: @Ruur generally speaking, in ruby, anonymous classes will be GC'd when they lose reference. The problem is that rails keeps track of all descendants or `ActiveRecord::Base` (which is what is happening when you call `Class.new(self)`  because `self` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`). This means that those classes never lose reference and thus never get GC'd which will bloat the memory

Comment: I understand better now. However, how do we go about freeing the memory used by the anonymous classes ? Restarting the application ?

Comment: @Ruur yes that would be about the only way or removing all the anonymous classes from the descendants Array as mentioned in the github issue.

Comment: We use this code in some specific scopes. So, the aliases we want to create are known beforehand. Now that I know that anonymous classes are kept in memory, can we write something like this to prevent creating the same anonymous class over and over ?
```ruby
klass_name = "#{table_alias}_table_alias".camelize
begin
  klass = klass_name.constantize
rescue NameError => e
  klass = Object.const_set(klass_name, Class.new(self))
  klass.all.source.left.table_alias = table_alias
  klass
end
```

Comment: @Ruur yes. I think the code could use some cleanup (mostly I don't like using rescue as a control flow mechanism) but creating a named class (constant) would avoid the memory issues I referenced as long as a the scope is limited and explicit. That being said I would move this out of `ApplicationRecord` and into a module so that you can actively control scope and in doing so I would create a method to set the alias at the class level and generate this subclass up front for delegation. I am not at a computer right now but I could put together an example when I get back to one.

Comment: @Ruur updated with my recommended implementation of your desired functionality. the Class is still anonymous but it is stored in a class instance variable for reuse.

Answer (score 2):

I added this method to ApplicationRecord

```rb
def self.alias_source(table_alias)
  klass = Class.new(self)
  klass.all.source.left.table_alias = table_alias
  klass
end
```

Now, I can do :

```rb
User.alias_source(:toto).where(firstname: nil) => "SELECT `toto`.* FROM `users` `toto` WHERE `toto`.`firstname` IS NULL"
```